# Delete rows by id and range condition?

Tags: range, amazon-dynamodb

I've been searching and searching for a way to delete items with the same ID by a range condition. None of the overloads for Table.DeleteItem seem to take a range condition, only a range.

Is there some other approach to deleting all entries older than an hour?

I'd prefer to not not have to retrieve all the matching hashkey rows and manually delete each row by the specific range key.

I'm primarily using the .NET SDK but any hints appreciated.

I see some batch write examples, but nothing that takes a whole range.

```
private static void SingleTableBatchWrite()
{
  Table productCatalog = Table.LoadTable(client, "ProductCatalog");
  var batchWrite = productCatalog.CreateBatchWrite();

  var book1 = new Document();
  book1["Id"] = 902;
  book1["Title"] = "My book1 in batch write using .NET Helper API";
  book1["ISBN"] = "902-11-11-1111";
  book1["Price"] = 10;
  book1["ProductCategory"] = "Book";
  book1["Authors"] = new List<string> { "Author 1", "Author 2", "Author 3" };
  book1["Dimensions"] = "8.5x11x.5";
  batchWrite.AddDocumentToPut(book1);
  // Specify delete item using overload that takes PK. 
  batchWrite.AddKeyToDelete(12345);
  Console.WriteLine("Performing batch write in SingleTableBatchWrite()");
  batchWrite.Execute();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality doesn't exist in DynamoDB.

The best you can do is Query for the appropriate items and manually delete each retrieved key.  You can save on the bandwidth by asking for only your hash and range key attributes when querying, but note that this doesn't save on read capacity; DynamoDB will still charge you for the full size of the item when returning a subset of its attributes.

Some people have tackled this temporal problem by making a separate table for each time period (more generally a day than an hour).  That way you can do some interesting things:

- Delete old data "for free" by dropping the table
- Scale today's table higher than the rest

This "data segregation" isn't as bad as it seems due to DynamoDB's model.  Need to get an item?  You already have the temporal range-key, so you know which table to ask.  Need to query?  Your Range condition must be time-based, so you know which tables to ask.

Comment: You don't have to return all fields- you can specify which attributes to get-- since you want to do a delete, you'd only get the hash/range.

Comment: I find it hard to understand why you can query on a range condition but not delete. It seems pretty straightforward in a linear system of indexed memory. Maybe they do want to you consume them precious bandwidth units  to delete.

Comment: @FlavorScape I think I covered your first comment in the first paragraph; but remember that you still pay for the full item size even if only getting the hash/range.

Comment: I was under the impression that internally all queries are asynchronous and you never have to get the whole object, why would they charge for attributes never retrieved?

Comment: @FlavorScape I'm not sure why; however from playing around with it I noticed that they do.  I wonder if it has something to do with memory usage on their end?  I think it's documented somewhere, I'll see if I can dig it up later.

Comment: Reference from DynamoDB confirming deletion only happens one record at a time: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.DeleteData.html If they change this functionality in the future, hopefully this page will note it.