# Query a dynamoDB table and delete result (with a loop)

Tags: laravel-4, amazon-dynamodb

I have an app that is keeping a record of [hash, number] and want to delete the record if I only have the hash. There should'nt be more than one record for each hash so batch delete is probably not the best option.

It is my understanding that I cant delete straight up usign the hash and will need to run a query and iteratoe over the result: [Delete rows by id and range condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167441/dynamodb-delete-rows-by-id-and-range-condition)

What I have so far:

```
   $dynamoDB = App::make('aws')->get('DynamoDb');
   $token = "usertoeknstringthatisthislong"

    $users = $dynamoDB->query(array(
        "TableName" => 'usertokens',
        "KeyConditions" => array(
            "token" => array(
                "AttributeValueList" => array (
                    array('S' => $token)
                ),
                "ComparisonOperator" => "EQ"
            )
        )
    ));
    return $users;

    foreach ($users as $user) {

        $dynamoDB->deleteItem(array(
            "TableName" => 'usertokens',
            "Key" => array(
                "token" => $token,
                "id" => $user
            )
        ));

    }
```

I am having trouble getting the syntax right (laravel-4) and getting an error "Validation errors: [Key][id] must be of type object [Key][token] must be of type object"

I have not been able to find a validator/lint program or some other means to debug. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found an [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-dynamodb.html#deleting-items) here for delete item

2 possible issues in your code:

1) your mapping from "token" to $token is not correct. see the example. "token" should be mapped to another associative array so DynamoDB knows whether the token is a number or a string. same for your "id" mapping.

2) also double check your iteration.

```
foreach ($users as $user)
```

because I think the actual items returned by the query is in the "Items" field of the query response. see [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPQuerying.html).

Comment: "also double check your iteration" Good call. One does need to do it as foreach (users['Items'] as $user).